# AtomicInteger doesn't seem to be working for me

Tags: java, multithreading, libgdx

I am trying to create a simple ten second countdown timer for my `Libgdx` game.  I have created a timekeep class which implements runnable and can do the ten second countdown fine.  However I want to print this `Timer` variable as it changes in my main game glass but I cannot do this for some reason.  I keep getting a nullpointer exception.  I figured it is probably a synchronization error since Render runs in its own thread and my timekeep runs its own thread.  I have tried volatile variables and a synchronized gettime method and now atomic integers with no success.  How can get the `Timer` variable from my timekeep class and print it from my main game class as it updates? Thanks

Here is my timekeep class

```
public class timekeep implements Runnable {
    public volatile Boolean TimerRunning = true;
    //private int Timer = 10;//I want to print this variable as it counts down
    public AtomicInteger Timer = new AtomicInteger(10);
    public int Timeleft;


    @Override

    public void run() {

        while (TimerRunning == true) {
            System.out.println("Time left" + Timer);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (Timer.equals(0)) {

                TimerRunning = false;

            } else {

                Timer.decrementAndGet();

            }

        }

    }

    public int getTimer() {
        return Timer.get();   
    }

}
```

Other Main game screen class
timekeep Timekeep;

```
 //constructor
 Timekeep = new timekeep();
 //on show create the thread
 timekeep Timekeep = new timekeep();//inside show method in main game screen class
 Thread t1 = new Thread(Timekeep);
 t1.start();
 //inside the render method 
 System.out.println(Timekeep.getTimer());//inside render method in main game screenclass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the

```
if(Timer.equals(0))
```

to

```
if (getTimer() == 0)
```

AtomicInteger doesnt override equals method . And you are passing primitive int 0 which will not equal to the Object AtomicInteger. Get the int value and compare to 0

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Sadly it still does not work.  It still crashes and I keep getting null pointer exception.  My countdown timer works fine its just getting the Timer value and using it in my main game screen which is seeming to be impossible.

Comment: what you mean by not working. i tried your code . it is displating 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0 and exit the while loop properly. where you are getting nullPointer ?

Comment: When the thread starts it runs properly and displays the information properly.  However in my main game screen class I am trying to access the Timer variable and draw it to my screen.  I get a null pointer exception when I try to do this.

Comment: Unless, we see your complete code we cant provide an suggestion. for the given code changing equals to == would solve and the thread would stop.

Comment: That is the complete code.  My thread works perfectly fine and prints fine to the log.  However I am trying to draw the countdown onto my actual game screen class by calling the getTimer() method.  When I call this method from my game screen class it crashes and gives null pointer exception.

Comment: No way , you can get Nullpoint at getTimer() method. because you use instance variable which is initiates while Object creates . Unless you set the Timer Object explicitly there is no reason for NullPointer

Comment: How would I get the Timer variable from my other class I can't seem to get it at all.  Even with calling the getTimer()method.  I think I was getting the  nullpointexception because I found a timekeep Timekeep; variable in my game class.

Comment: Please post your other class.

Comment: `timekeep.Timer`. (But please, rename it. Classes start with an uppercase letter and variables with a lowercase. So `Timekeep.timer` would be correct.)

Comment: Oh, sorry. I was wrong. `Timer` is not `static` in your case. So it would be `instanceOfTimekeep.Timer` (where `instanceOfTimer` is the variable you created with `Timekeep instanceOfTimer = new Timekeep()`)

Comment: Ok I have edited the above code to include the relevant parts of the other class.  They are at the bottom.  On show screen I create the thread and instantiate timekeep object.  However I also did that up in my constructor so I could call timekeep.getTimer() in my render method.  This doesn't work because there is two objects the same.  If I change one to timekeep2 and do timekeep2.getTimer() it constantly prints 10 instead of the countdown.  What is the best way for me to get the Timer variable from within this class? Thanks

Comment: I have just created another Thread within my main class and it is working there fine as expected.  I would rather have created it in a separate class but for some reason I wasn't able to get the up to date Timer variable.  Thanks all for your help.